# API architecture for Web App

Tags: angularjs, web-services, api, web-applications

I am creating a web app having 7 different sections-
[image: Web App view]

All the sections correlate with courseOrderId, its basically a order detail page. So, should I use just 1 API to fetch data and bind on frontend or should I call 7 different section specific API's.

In my case, I am using AngularJs2 and there are about 20 different sections. What is the best practice to implement this kind of Web App? Single API or Multiple APIs?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to go with multiple API's architecture. It is more easy to manage and right now best practice to follow in development. You can also refer to this link for more details.
http://busypeoples.github.io/post/thinking-in-components-angular-js/